# SQL query to set CHECK constraint on a column based on the value in other column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I need to set a CHECK constraint on a column based on the value in other column (both within the same table)

Like when COLUMN A is NULL, COLUMN B should be NULL
But if COLUMN A has values 1 or 2 or 3 then COLUMN B should definitely have a date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `B` as a date.  And then use a check constraint:

```
create table t (
    . . .
    b date,
    constraint chk_t_b check (b is null or a not in (1, 2, 3)),
    . . .
);
```

If `b` is a string and you just want it to "look" like a date, then you can do something like:

```
create table t (
    . . .
    b date,
    constraint chk_t_b check (regexp_like(b, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$') or a not in (1, 2, 3)),
    . . .
);
```

The date matching isn't exact, but you haven't specified the format for the "date" if the column really stores a string.

Answer (score 1):

The `CHECK` constraint you want could take the form:

```
alter table t add constraint chk1
  check (a is null and b is null or a in (1, 2) and b is not null);
```

Comment: This query worked perfectly for my case. Thank you so much!